# What's a word for the act or practice of creating new words?

Tags: word-request

is there any word in English that refers to the act or practice of creating new words? There are certain disciplines and some particular persons who practices those disciplines which are all the time creating new words, does this action have a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible term can be [Neologist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neologist) , which is defined as

> a proponent of a new doctrine
>
> an advocate of [neology](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neology)

[Neologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism) is a relatively recent or isolated term, word, or phrase that may be in the process of entering common use, but that has not yet been fully accepted into mainstream language.

Neologisms are often created by combining existing words or by giving words new and unique suffixes or prefixes. They can become popular through memetics, by way of mass media, the Internet, and word of mouth, and often become accepted parts of the language.

Examples include **laser** (1960) from Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation, **robotics** (1941), **agitprop** (1930).

Comment: logo means word, right? and neo is new? so Neology could be seen as the act of creating new word aside of "a proponent of a new doctrine"?

Answer (score 2):

The process of naming something is called **[nomenclature](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nomenclature)**.

The study of origin of names is **[etymology](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/etymology)**.

Answer (score 2):

COIN (vt):

2. Invent (a new word or phrase)
   ‘he coined the term ‘desktop publishing’’

Source: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coin